# Change header Background color in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am new in React native and trying to display header Bar (Navigation Bar )background color.
Below some approach which tried.

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <NavigationBar 

  title= {titleConfig}
  />
  </View>

);

 }
}

const titleConfig = {
    title: 'XYZ',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#2ec76e',
  },

  };

const styles ={
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#24686e',


    },
  }
```

Comment: only Title background colour will work fine !!!!

Answer (score 1):

would you Mind showing the Screen Shot of what you get when you run this 
and as far i know the below styling would do the header

```
container: {
    backgroundColor:'#F8F8F8',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 8,
    borderWidth:0,
    shadowColor:'#F8F8F8',
    shadowOffset:{ width:0, height:2 },
    shadowOpacity:0.5,
    elevation:2,
    position: 'relative'

    },
textStyle:{
    fontSize:25

   }
```

Comment: did you mean the styling/css?

Comment: you dont have to do it all the time. either you can copy and paste the code that i have given above for a header or your can use the various libraries that are available in the github. one such example is React-native-navbar [https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar]